# Run related Ubuntu commands using scala process

Tags: linux, bash, scala, ubuntu, hadoop

I have an Ubuntu machine with a native Hadoop client installed on it, meaning i can run for example:
**hadoop fs -ls** as long as I'm on a certain user, let's say userA.
Now i have a scala application running on this machine under root (cannot change this) and i need to be able to switch to userA and then run **hadoop fs -ls**
I'm working with scala.process in order to run my commands but I'm unable to run them in way they'll be connected to each other, so if run:
**Process(Seq("bash","-c","su userA && hadoop fs -ls")).!** i will get an error since the 2nd command is actually executed on root, i know this because when i do: 
**Process(Seq("bash","-c","su userA && whoami")).!** I get **root** and not **userA**
Any idea how to tie them together (exmple in linux command will suffice, i'll be able to replicate it in scala.process i believe)

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with Scala, Ubuntu or Hadoop per se. It is all about shell scripting and understanding the way shell works.

First of all, you don't need to invoke bash, in your case it is just another (unnecessary) layer of indirection. Removing bash with leave you with this:

```
Process("su userA && hadoop fs -ls").!
```

... which will fail. Why? Because this code is equivalent to this:

```
Process(Seq("su", "userA", "&&", "hadoop", "fs", "-ls")).!
```

As you can see all the pieces of your command including `&&` are passed to `su` as command line arguments. Naturally `su` doesn't know what to do with it and thus would fail.

---

Now let's forget about Scala code for a while and drop to bash shell and try the command there. Let's use `whoami` to test whether the user has changed to **userA**:

```
su userA && whoami
```

The fist thing that you would notice is that `su` when invoked this way provides interactive shell prompt (asking for password first, unless you run it from **root**). This is probably not what you want when running `su` from a program. Moreover, after you log out of that shell you will see that the user was not changed to **userA**.

Here's why. The notion of *effective user* is tied to a process. Each process has exactly one *effective user* at a given point of time. The initial *effective user* of a process is inherited from the spawning process.

So here's what's happening when you run `su userA && whoami` from the bash prompt:

1. `bash` spawns `su` as a child process, `su` inherits the *effective user* from its parent:

   ```
   bash (root)
   +- su (root)
   ```
2. `su` changes its *effective user* via [setuid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/setuid.2.html):

   ```
   bash (root)
   +- su (userA)
   ```
3. by default `su` spawns the default shell of a specified user as given in `/etc/passwd` as a child process (e.g. `sh`); `sh` inherits the *effective user* from its parent:

   ```
   bash (root)
   +- su (userA)
      +- sh (userA)
   ```

Now let's get to the the `&&` part. It turns out to be part of the shell syntax. `command1 && command2` asks shell to run *command1* first and then **only after** *command1* exists without any errors (i.e. its exit code is zero) run *command2*. It is crucial to understand two things:

1. *command2* is run only **after** *command1* has **finished successfully**;
2. both *command1* and *command2* are spawned by the same shell process, and thus they both inherit its *effective user*.

So here's what we would get for `su userA && whoami` invocation:

```
bash (root)
+- su (userA, already exited by the time whoami started)
|  +- sh (userA, already exited by the time whoami started)
+- whoami (root)
```

So no matter what user would you change to via `su` process `whoami` wouldn't be affected.

In order to fix the issue you should make `whoami` to be spawned by `su` so that it could inherit the changed user.

To make this happen invoke `su` like this:

```
su -c whoami
```

This would yield the following process tree:

```
bash (root)
+- su (userA)
   +- whoami (userA)
```

---

Now let's get back to Scala. Unfortunately if you run the command above from Scala you would get `su: must be run from a terminal`. To be honest I don't know how to cope with this problem properly, so I would suggest to switch to `sudo` instead.

So the final solution would be:

```scala
Process(Seq("sudo", "-u", "userA", "hadoop fs -ls")).!
```